# Formatar código nas respostas do Stack Overflow

Tags: suporte, formatação, markdown

Como colocar código HTML ou JavaScript para responder no stack?

Comment: Seleciona o código e clica em "amostra de código", seu símbolo é `{}`

Comment: Quando quiser ver como outros usuários usam a formatação, clique em `editar` abaixo do post e confira; tomando bastante cuidado para `cancelar` a edição depois do confere.

Comment: Escreve ou cole o código, seleciona tudo e depois clica em formatar: Trecho JavaScript/HTML/CSS (Ctrl-M)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dê 4 espaços antes de inserir o código, como exemplo abaixo.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
          print("Ola mundo!");

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado! :D

Comment: Acho que é a primeira vez que vejo alguém começar participando num site [se] através de uma resposta no Meta :)

Comment: @brasofilo com direito a resposta aceita e tudo :)

Answer (score 5):

Veja esse link, consta todas as opções da ferramenta que estão disponíveis https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help